# Search/Append text to input field, separated by comma

Tags: javascript, html

I'm going to make a input field, and when the user clicks it a dropdown will appear, containing lines of text. If the user click on one of the lines, then it will be appended to the input field, and if more is clicked then separate them with comma.

This is how I'm thinking it should work.
[Image of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4eAm.png)

How should I make this, so I by clicking on the dropdown element build the input string?

Comment: How is that even related to PHP? Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: I'm creating all my pages in php, so I thought that tag was relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by declaring an event listener for the container of the items and checking if the target of the click event is an item, for example with `e.target.tagName == "LI"` (alternatively you could declare an event listener for each item in a for loop). Then you grab its text with `e.target.textContent` and the value of the input and append the text to the value. With a small terniary operator check you can evaluate if a comma is necessary or not `inputValue != "" ? ", " : ""`.

**Working example:**

```js
let list = document.querySelector('ul');

list.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == "LI") {
    let inputValue = document.querySelector('#version').value;
    inputValue = inputValue + (inputValue != "" ? ", " : "") + e.target.textContent;

    document.querySelector('#version').value = inputValue;
  }
});
```

```html
<label for="version">Version</label>
<input id="version" name="version" value="" placeholder="Choose version...">

<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```